# Show different image based on time

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to make a code that will show two different images depending on what the time is and what day it is.

I want it to show an image that says "open" between 7:25 - 12:40 and 13:30 - 14:10 when it's between the days monday to friday. On weekends and at any other time it should show the image "closed".

Here's the code I've been trying to get to work.

```
    <?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');

$h = date('Gi'); //G (timer) = 0 til 23 og i (minutter) = 00 til 59

$d = date('N'); //1 (for mandag) til 7 (for søndag)


// MANDAG
if ($d = '1' && $h >= 745 && $h < 1240) $img = 'images/open.png';
if ($d = '1' && $h >= 1330 && $h < 1410) $img = 'images/open_red.png';

// TIRSDAG
if ($d = '2' && $h >= 745 && $h < 1240) $img = 'images/open.png';
if ($d = '2' && $h >= 1330 && $h < 1410) $img = 'images/open_red.png';

// ONSDAG
if ($d = '3' && $h >= 745 && $h < 1240) $img = 'images/open.png';
if ($d = '3' && $h >= 1330 && $h < 1410) $img = 'images/open_red.png';

// TORSDAG
if ($d = 4 && $h >= 745 && $h < 1240) $img = 'images/open.png';
if ($d = 4 && $h >= 1330 && $h < 1410) $img = 'images/open_red.png';

// FREDAG
if ($d = 5 && $h >= 745 && $h < 1240) $img = 'images/open.png';

// LØRDAG


// SØNDAG


else $img = 'images/closed.png';
?>

<img src="<?php echo $img; ?>">
```

For some reason it ignores the day variable and simply print out the last entry, that being "fredag" (friday).

Comment: The comparison operator is `==`. `=` is assignment

Comment: If you want to use this as a template, make the image closed first instead of using an else. Use `==` to compare days, and use braces `{}` for each if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If actually falls into a number of the different `if` branches, but overwrites `$img` each successive time.

Your main issue is that you aren't comparing `$d` to things, but rather assigning `$d` values each time.  For comparison you want the double equal sign: `==` as in `if ($d == 5 && ...`

Also, you might consider an if, else if, else ladder instead of a number of if statements.  As it stands, if the first `if` statement is the "correct" one, the `$img` will still be set to `closed.png` because it fails the last `if` statement.

Had you correctly used an if,else if, else ladder, this wouldn't happen (and your script would run a bit faster).

---

***TLDR:*** This should work:

```
$h = date('Gi'); //G (timer) = 0 til 23 og i (minutter) = 00 til 59

$d = date('N'); //1 (for mandag) til 7 (for søndag)


// MANDAG
if ($d == 1 && $h >= 745 && $h < 1240){ $img = 'images/open.png'; }
elseif ($d == 1 && $h >= 1330 && $h < 1410){ $img = 'images/open_red.png'; }

// TIRSDAG
elseif ($d == 2 && $h >= 745 && $h < 1240){ $img = 'images/open.png'; }
elseif ($d == 2 && $h >= 1330 && $h < 1410){ $img = 'images/open_red.png'; }

// ONSDAG
elseif ($d == 3 && $h >= 745 && $h < 1240){ $img = 'images/open.png'; }
elseif ($d == 3 && $h >= 1330 && $h < 1410){ $img = 'images/open_red.png'; }

// TORSDAG
elseif ($d == 4 && $h >= 745 && $h < 1240){ $img = 'images/open.png'; }
elseif ($d == 4 && $h >= 1330 && $h < 1410){ $img = 'images/open_red.png'; }

// FREDAG
elseif ($d == 5 && $h >= 745 && $h < 1240){ $img = 'images/open.png'; }

// LØRDAG


// SØNDAG


else{ $img = 'images/closed.png'; }
?>

<img src="<?php echo $img; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

A fundamental flaw is that you should use `==` (that *tests* if two values are equal) instead of `=` (that *assigns* a value). But most of the code is cumbersome and the whole routine can be written in a far more compact way. Just try:

```
$h = date('Gi'); 
$d = date('N');

$img = "images/closed.png";

if ( ($d >= 1 && $d <= 6) && ($h >= 745 && $h < 1240) ) $img = "images/open.png";
elseif ( ($d >= 1 && $d <= 5) && ($h >= 1330 && $h < 1410) ) $img = "images/open_red.png";
```

That's all :)

Comment: I will be adding all kinds of different times and days where different stores are open. That's why I have one for each day, as a template.

Answer (score 0):

You use `=` which assigns, when you should use `==` which compares.

Your `else` also attaches to the last `if`, so you will only see an "open" image when it is Friday. Use braces to make the if/elseif/else structure more clear to yourself.

A better way is to make it "closed" by default, and then use an if/else structure (with braces, always with braces!) like the following:

```
$h = date('Gi'); //G (timer) = 0 til 23 og i (minutter) = 00 til 59

$d = date('N'); //1 (for mandag) til 7 (for søndag)

$img = 'images/closed.png'; // By default the image is "closed"

if ($d < 6) // If Monday to Friday
{
    if ($h >= 745 and $h < 1240) // If early
    {
        $img = 'images/open.png'; // then it's open
    } 
    elseif ($h >= 1330 and $h < 1410 and $day != 5) // If late, and NOT Friday
    { 
        $img = 'images/open_red.png'; // then it's red open
    }
}

?>

<img src="<?php echo $img; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something around the lines of this:

```
list($day_of_week, $hour_minute) = explode(' ', date('N Gi'));

 switch( $day_of_week ) {
    case '7':
    case '6':
        # weekend days, always closed:
        $image = 'closed.png';
    break;
    default:
        # weekdays, so check the time instead:
        if ( ( (int)$hour_minute >= 745 && (int)$hour_minute <= 1240 ) || ( (int)$hour_minute >= 1330 && (int)$hour_minute <= 1410 ) ) {
            $image = 'open.png';
        } else {
            $image = 'closed.png';
        }
    break;
}
```

Pretty straight forward and simple to read imho